# No funciona Composer "Unable to load dynamic library"

Tags: php, composer

Installo composer sobre Linu con líneas de comandos siguientes :

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

le moví en `/usr/local/bin/` para haberlo en global.

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Cuando hizo `$ composer --version` me dice :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10 09:29:45
```

Me da la version pero No me consuela que esta `Unable to load dynamic library` aunque ya esta `.dll` ficheros y entonces ficheros windows.

Sin embargo cuando hizo `$ php composer.phar self-update` antes de cargar bundle por Symfony me repuesta :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

Pueden ayudarme cargar estos ?

---

Aqui esta mi php version :

```
$php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

No sé como obtener mi servidor version sobre Linux,  hice lo siguiente pero me habla de R...  :

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

Comment: puedes agregar mas detalles como: version del servidor y de php , intentastes ver si la dll se encuentra en esa ruta

Comment: @JackNavaRow he añadido mi php version pero no se como obtener el version del servidor

Comment: notastes que tienes intalado PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )